# How use atexit() function for free up memory?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, atexit

This is  simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void cleanUp(){
    printf("I have to do free up memory\n");
}

int main(){

    char *temp;

    temp = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char)); 

    atexit(cleanUp);

    exit(0);

    free(temp);

    return 0;
}
```

When the program will exit, how can I free up the memory. Function 'cleanUp' have no parameter. So how can I free up the memory in function 'cleanUp' for no memory leak.

Comment: cleanUp function should be `void(*)(void)`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thank you. There should be an award/badge for that effort.

Comment: No, but everyone who answers a dupe should be answer-banned for a day :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Interesting strategy. We definitely shouldn't ban askers. But newbie answerers aren't aware of dups and shouldn't be punished. I think positive reinforcement should be used.

Comment: Its work for malloc. What can I do for close an open file?